# update elements using numpy array function

Tags: python, algorithm, numpy

I am trying to implement k-mean clustering algorithm for small project. I came upon [this article](http://stanford.edu/~cpiech/cs221/handouts/kmeans.html) which suggest that

> K-Means is much faster if you write the update functions using operations on numpy arrays, instead of manually looping over the arrays and updating the values yourself.

I am exactly using iteration over each element of array to update it. For each element in dataset `z`, I am assigning the cluster array from nearest centroid via iteration through each element.

```
    for i in range(z):
        clstr[i] = closest_center(data[i], cen)
```

and my update function is

```
def closest_center(x, clist):
    dlist = [fabs(x - i) for i in clist]
    return clist[dlist.index(min(dlist))]
```

Since I am using grayscale image, I am using absolute value to calculate the Euclidean distance.

I noticed that `opencv` has this algorithm too. It takes less than 2s to execute the algorithm while mine takes more than 70s. May I know what the article is suggesting?

My images are imported as gray scale and is represented as 2d numpy array. I further converted into 1d array because it's easier to process 1d array.

Comment: Why do you want to implement this yourself? `scipy` already has a k-means clustering algorithm for you.

Comment: @AkshatMahajan As a small project in image processing. I already have access to  it via OpenCV. Still I have to it without using inbuilt function.

Comment: you should share more of your code, in order to have a better idea. Also shouldn't you use the euclidean distance ?

Comment: @Romain for greyscale image, there is only one element. So, Euclidean distance is same as absolute value as in real number line.

Comment: @SantoshLinkha A fairly big part of it is probably implementation in C vs python.

Comment: @Natecat while installing OpenCV I copied `cv2.pyd` into library. Probably I should make use of C++ from python too. I don't know how :(

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The list comprehension is likely to slow down execution. I would suggest to **vectorize** the function `closest_center`. This is straightforward for 1-dimensional arrays:

```
import numpy as np

def closest_center(x, clist):
    return clist[np.argmin(np.abs(x - clist))]
```